# AWS SQS FIFO Queue: How to set MessageGroupId on Send Message component of Mule 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, amazon-sqs, fifo

**UseCase**: Sending message to AWS SQS FIFO queue name *muleTesting.fifo* using Mule Amazon SQS Connector 5.6

**Implementing**: https://docs.mulesoft.com/amazon-sqs-connector/5.6/amazon-sqs-connector-examples

**Question**: How do I add the MessageGrouperID parameter on SendMessageRequest using Mule SQS Connector, the following is giving error on SendMessage Mule Component:

```
{
    body: "Hello World",
    messageAttributes: {
        "AccountId": {
            "stringValue" : "000123456",
            "dataType" : "String.AccountId"
        } as Object {
            class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.MessageAttributeValue"
        },
        "NumberId": {
            "stringValue" : "230.000000000000000001",
            "dataType" : "Number"
        } as Object {
            class : "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.MessageAttributeValue"
        }
    } as Object {
        class: "java.util.HashMap"
    }
} as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.Message"
}
```

**Error**:

> "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter; Request ID: 43ce279b-5972-5df0-bff5-706ac30f8b29; Proxy: null)"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a groupId property to your payload like this.

```
{
    body: "Hello World",
    groupId: "GroupName",
    messageAttributes: {
        "AccountId": {
            "stringValue" : "000123456",
            "dataType" : "String.AccountId"
        } as Object {
            class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.MessageAttributeValue"
        },
        "NumberId": {
            "stringValue" : "230.000000000000000001",
            "dataType" : "Number"
        } as Object {
            class : "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.MessageAttributeValue"
        }
    } as Object {
        class: "java.util.HashMap"
    }
} as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.Message"
}
```